# Sql server replication - reinitialize from an ID onwards?

Tags: sql-server

I am using transactional publication that is replicating 1 large sql server table that only ever has inserts (no updates or deletes).
It has > 60 billion rows, and its currently stopped for 6 days

The subscription error is currently saying:
The subscription(s) have been marked inactive and must be reinitialized. NoSync subscriptions will need to be dropped and recreated.

I simply want to look at the PK ID on the replication server and the main server and just start copying over the data that is missing

Is this possible? and how would I reinitialize the subscription.
I tried reinitialize it already but it locked the table and caused no end of issues.

sql server 2017 enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a [Static Row Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/define-and-modify-a-static-row-filter?view=sql-server-ver16) to your Publication for this large table. In the filter you would specify the `ID` that you want to start from. Assuming your `ID` column is incremental, the predicate clause would look like this for example: `WHERE ID >= 1234567`

Steps from the linked docs:

> 1. On the Filter Table Rows page of the New Publication Wizard or the Filter Rows page of the Publication Properties -  dialog
>    box, the action you take depends on the type of publication:
>
>    - For a snapshot or transactional publication, click Add.
> 2. In the Add Filter dialog box, select a table to filter from the drop-down list box.
> 3. Create a filter statement in the Filter statement text area. You can type directly in the text area, and you can also drag and drop
>    columns from the Columns list box.
> 4. Select OK.
> 5. If you are in the Publication Properties -  dialog box, click OK to save and close the dialog box.

You'll also want to edit the Article properties, and set the "**Action if name is in use**" property to "Keep existing object unchanged". This will ensure when you re-initialize that the data that's already replicated to the Subscriber doesn't get deleted. The only downside is if you need re-initialize again in the future, you'll need to manually update the `ID` in the Row Filter so you don't accidentally attempt to insert the same data twice.

Also, please note that there is some overhead on the Publisher server for using a Static Row Filter. But I've never experienced any issues from using this feature.

---

The other route you can try going is [Initializing a Transactional Subscription from a Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-from-a-backup?view=sql-server-ver16). Though this may take longer and I'm not sure how feasible it would be for a table that's 60 billion rows big. But here's the steps from the linked docs anyway:

> 1. For an existing publication, ensure that the publication supports the ability to initialize from backup by executing [sp_helppublication (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helppublication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) at the Publisher on the publication database. Note the value of allow_initialize_from_backup in the result set.
>
>    - If the value is 1, the publication supports this functionality.
>    - If the value is 0, execute [sp_changepublication (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changepublication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) at the Publisher on the publication database. Specify a value of
>      allow_initialize_from_backup for @property and a value of true for
>      @value.
> 2. Create a backup of the publication database using the [BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement.
> 3. Restore the backup on the Subscriber using the [RESTORE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement.
> 4. At the Publisher on the publication database, execute the stored procedure [sp_addsubscription (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Specify the following
>    parameters:
>
>    - @sync_type - a value of initialize with backup.
>    - @backupdevicetype - the type of backup device: logical (default), disk, or tape.
>    - @backupdevicename - the logical or physical backup device to use for the restore.
>    - For a logical device, specify the name of the backup device specified when sp_addumpdevice was used to create the device.
>    - For a physical device, specify a complete path and file name, such as DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\BACKUP\Mybackup.dat' or TAPE = '\.\TAPE0'.
>    - (Optional) @password - a password that was provided when the backup set was created.
>    - (Optional) @mediapassword - a password that was provided when the media set was formatted.
>    - (Optional) @fileidhint - identifier for the backup set to be restored. For example, specifying 1 indicates the first backup set on
>      the backup medium and 2 indicates the second backup set.
>    - (Optional for tape devices) @unload - specify a value of 1 (default) if the tape should be unloaded from the drive after the restore is
>      complete and 0 if it should not be unloaded.
> 5. (Optional) For a pull subscription, execute [sp_addpullsubscription (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addpullsubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [sp_addpullsubscription_agent (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addpullsubscription-agent-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) at the Subscriber on the subscription database. For more information, see [Create a Pull Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/create-a-pull-subscription?view=sql-server-ver16).
> 6. (Optional) Start the Distribution Agent. For more information, see [Synchronize a Pull Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-a-pull-subscription?view=sql-server-ver16) or [Synchronize a Push Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-a-push-subscription?view=sql-server-ver16).